# javascript imageSwap issue

Tags: javascript, image, setinterval, nodelist

My `setInteval()` function keeps restart if I called back the main function more than once.

I have tried a lot of techniques , but wasn't able to get the right implementation.

#### The idea:

About each `<div>` has its own `id` and its child images.

I want to make a swap of that images every 1 second and in another div in 3 seconds.

```
(function(){
  var count = 0;

  function swapImages(id,speed){
    var elChilds = $(id).children().length;

    setInterval(function(){
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      if(count >= elChilds){
        count= 0;
      }
    }, speed);

    if($(id).children().hasClass('image'+count)){
      $(id).children().removeClass('active');
      $('.absolute-image.image'+count).addClass('active');
    }

  }

  swapImages('#swap0', 1000);
  swapImages('#swap1', 5000);
  swapImages('#swap2', 2000);

})();
 <div class="col-md-3 main-content-left" id="swap0">
      <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image2">
        <img src="images/gal3.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
       <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image1">
        <img src="images/gal2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
       <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image0 active">
        <img src="images/gal1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>


        <div class="col-md-5" id="swap1">
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image2">
            <img src="images/gal1.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image1">
            <img src="images/gal2.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image0 active">
            <img src="images/gal3.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" id="swap2">
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image2">
            <img src="images/gal3.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image1">
            <img src="images/gal2.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="" class="col-md-12 absolute-image image0 active">
            <img src="images/gal3.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please explain better your problem.

Comment: the idea is about images swap function and remove the active class from all images and put it with the current count state/number

when i try to call back more than one function gets confused.

Comment: Please show us the html code also

Comment: done and you will find that we have `id="swap0 , swap1, swap2....etc"`

Answer (score 0):

What I understood was you are calling the main
function more than one time but your setInterval is getting reset

If my understanding is right, Keep your setInterval under a
if condition and set a boolean value to the session or local storage and the
if condition

Set the boolean value whenever you want the setInterval to reset or not

Updated code

```
(function() {
var count = 0;

function swapImages(id, speed) {
    var elChilds = $(id).children().length;

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('flagSetInterval') == null) {
        setInterval(function() {
            count++;
            sessionStorage.setItem('flagSetInterval', 'false');
            console.log(count);
            if (count >= elChilds) {
                count = 0;
            }
        }, speed);
    }

    if ($(id).children().hasClass('image' + count)) {
        $(id).children().removeClass('active');
        $('.absolute-image.image' + count).addClass('active');
    }

}

swapImages('#swap0', 1000);
swapImages('#swap1', 5000);
swapImages('#swap2', 2000);
})();
```

Comment: please let us know if its worked or not ,it may help for someone else :)

Comment: no it didn't worked well maybe if you could make it with a fiddle please